# How to get the Language ID of Word dynamically

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to get the language id of Word dynamically and assign it to Custom Dictionaries language id. I can do this when I know the language the Word is using **Word.WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUS**;. But how to get this dynamically. I tried as below but get a casting error. I can do this easily in VB6 but need a solution in c#.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoLanguageID' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLanguageID'

**C#**

```
oCustDict.LanguageSpecific = true;
oCustDict.LanguageID = WordApp.Language;
```

**VB6 - Works**

```
Dim lCurrentLanguage As Long
CurrentLanguage = WordApp.Language
oCustDict.LanguageSpecific = True
oCustDict.LanguageID = lCurrentLanguage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 was notoriously bad at enforcing variable types - it would jump through invisible hoops to try to stuff data of one type into a variable of a different type, often incorrectly.

C# is much stricter about type conversions, and in 99.9% of cases that's a good thing. In this particular case, it looks like the two enums have the same values, so you just need to add an explicit cast:

```
oCustDict.LanguageID = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLanguageID)WordApp.Language;
```